# Using flow map to move points/bounding

Tags: computer-vision, opticalflow

I'm trying to use the output of a network called FlowNet to move a few certain points(e.g: at pixel 441) however the output of the network is 1/16 of the input size (probably due to convolution).

If the flow map was of the same size as the input image, I guess it would have been pretty straight forward to move the corresponding point according to displacement(e.g: adding just the x,y displacement for pixel 441). How do I go about moving points with a flow map that is smaller than the input size? Do I have to upsample/deconvolute it first?

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the lukas-kanade algorithm for this simple task, refer to [opencv tutuorial](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/dee/tutorial_optical_flow.html)

Comment: I've already tried LK algorithm but i didn't get very good accuracy(perhaps because the objects were moving a bit fast) so I wondered whether a CNN-based optical flow method like FlowNet would work better. (The flow map looked pretty good but it's somehow not of the same size as the input image)

Comment: Have you tried simple upsampling (i.e. bilinearly)?

Comment: Thanks! I looked around and I found a paper called "Deep Feature Flow" that uses the output of "FlowNet" to warp feature maps and they used Bilinear Sampling(will try that out..)